# Параметры и аргументы функций в Go

Tags: golang

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по двум вопросам.

1) Можно ли в Go писать функции с необязательными параметрами? Типа как в PHP

```
function MyFunc($var1, $var2 = 1){}
```

2) Есть ли в Go возможность передавать значение переменной по ссылке? Опять же, как в PHP

```
function MyFunc($var1, &$var2){ $var2 = 1;}
```

После PHP этих приятных мелочей очень не хватает, а гугление что-то в этот раз не помогло.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- опциональных параметров нету
- функция должна возвращать значение, а не изменять аргумент
- не стоит писать на одном языке в стиле другого языка

Comment: Спасибо! Это собственно все что требовалось. Буду привыкать :)

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Можно ли в Go писать функции с необязательными параметрами? Типа как в PHP

Точно также -- нет. Но есть пути обхода, своего рода костыли:

1. Можно принимать переменное кол-во аргументов(`func (params... interface{})`), и тогда аргументы будут опциональными. Правда не именованными.
2. Можно передавать словарь `map[string]interface{}`, немного громоздко, но иногда другого выхода нет.

> 2) Есть ли в Go возможность передавать значение переменной по ссылке? Опять-же как в PHP

В Go нет ссылок, но есть указатели. Передавайте по указателю.

**UPD**: пример использования указателя.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f(i *int) {
    (* i) = 2
}

func main() {
    i := 1
    f(&i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Напечатает 2.

Comment: Указатель != ссылка. Изменяя ссылку в ф-и, изменения видны вне ф-и. Если присвоить новый адрес указателю внутри ф-и, адрес указателя во вне не изменится. Следовательно, для нужд, про которые говорил автор нельзя использовать указатели.

Comment: Для чего нельзя их использовать? Я могу менять значения хранящиеся вне функции через указатели. Что ещё нужно?

Comment: См. вопрос:

    function MyFunc($var1, &$var2){ $var2 = 1;}

Comment: @Expert, всё можно. Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: Разадресация - это здорово, но речь шла совсем о другом. 

    foo(a &A) {
        a = a1
    }

и 

    foo(a *A) {
        a = new(A)
    }

Совсем разне разные.

Comment: А, я понял вас.

> для нужд, про которые говорил автор нельзя использовать указатели.

автор:

> Есть ли в Go возможность передавать значение переменной по ссылке? Опять же, как в PHP

Ну да.

Comment: Врядли автор хотел этого.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется сделать параметр который не обязательно передавать в функцию не сложно.
Значение поумолчанию можно прописать внутри.
у меня получилось так:

    `package main
    import "fmt"
    func addText(base string, opt ...string) (s string) {
        if len(opt) > 0 {
            base += opt[0]
        } else {
            base += "-" //хорошее место для обработки параметра поумолчанию
        }
    return base
    }
    func main() {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", addText("info: "))
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", addText("info: ", "done"))
    }`

Пожалуйста не сильно ругайте, я новичёк на стековерфлоу...